# What is a 'disjunct' of a union called?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Say I have a set $C = A \cup B$ and I want to refer to $A$ in natural language. Had the expression been a Boolean formula with a disjunction, then I would call $A$ the first disjunct.

Is there a similar term when speaking about unions?

The context is the following. I have a set $C$ defined as the union of two unnamed sets with long descriptions: $C = \{a \in U : \dots \} \cup \{b \in U : \dots \}$. After the definition of $C$, I would like to clarify the role of each of the two sets, using a sentence like

The first **???** ensures that $C$ ... while the second **???** guarantees that $C$ is ...

As the description for each set is long, and space scares, I cannot refer to them by that. I am not interested in wasting space introducing names for the sets, as they are referred to directly only once.

Comment: I would use "$A$".

Comment: How about "term in the union"? For example, the first term in the union is $A$, and the second is $B$.

Comment: I'm always puzzled by this kind of questions. Not everything has a name; is it pure curiosity, or do you have a real reason to want a name for this?

Comment: I like 'component', but I'd only really use this to refer to disjoint unions, for example, "let $i : A \to C$ be the inclusion of the first component of the disjoint union".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Why the hostility? It might be that the OP is writing something and wants to know if there's terminology for something; seems like a reasonable enough question to me.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: I didn't mean to be hostile, maybe I could have phrased that better. If it's really a question about terminology, then okay, let's find out how it's called. But if it's a question about how to write mathematics, giving alternatives like Asaf did is a better idea IMO. *I* can't envision a situation where I would need such a terminology, but maybe the OP is in such a situation, so it would be good to have  some context, ultimately.

Comment: With the new context, I would just write "the first set in the union", "the second set in the union". Clear and to the point, IMO.

Comment: No hostility felt. I have added context.

Comment: First term, second term sounds OK.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are describing $C$ as the union of two ***sets***, why not simply refer to $A$ as the first ***set*** in this union of two sets.

But, honestly, I'd simply refer to these sets by name. If you state that $C = A\cup B$, why not go on to assert:

"Set $A$ ensures...., while $B$ guarantees..."

Comment: This is very reasonable, and what I ended up doing, as nothing shorter was suggested. However it feels like "cheating" - like referring to $\phi$ in $\phi \lor \psi$ as the first **formula** in this disjunction of formulas ;) As mentioned in the question, referring by name was not feasible in the particular situation.

Comment: Hmmm. Perhaps refer to $A$ as "the first of the united sets...., while the second ....... I'm quite sure it would scream out as awkward if one were to refer to $A$ as "the first unionand..." (since union is similar to "sum" hence sumand while intersection is similar to "product");, or "the first unionee", as those terms haven't any uptake.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize all of the suggestions, as of writing this:

- Set
- Term
- Use the explicit name introduced earlier
- Unionand
- Unionee
- Component (only suggested for disjoint unions)

---

My personal thoughts and feelings: I want a good, distinct term for this.  Because I often want to have a nice, sing-songy, catchy expression for countable additivity.  For instance, something like "The measure of the union is the sum of the measures of the ..."  I want to delay introducing symbols and try to give a more natural-language expression if I possibly can.

I would suggest "unit" for one term/set in a union, suggesting that it is what "exists" before it is united with other terms/sets.  Unfortunately mathematicians use "unit" a bit too much for other concepts, so I don't think this is the best route.

I don't want something that sounds so confusing as "unionand", especially when I suspect that its analog "summand" comes from some rule of Latin and "unionand" probably doesn't conform to the same rule.

In other contexts, we talk about a "union" between man and wife, or between states.  But I think we'd all find it really weird to call a term/set a "spouse" or "ally".

---

How about we just bite the bullet and use something silly and fun?  Like a "uny".

Each little uny in the union.  :)